Installed Ubuntu without connecting to the Internet; what am I missing from that?
I just used a bootable USB stick to replace Windows on my desktop with Ubuntu. Then, when I was going through the Ubuntu installer, one section asked me to connect to the Internet to "improve my installation with compatibility check and extra software packages". I was unable to connect to a network, so I chose to complete the installation without wi-fi.
Now, my question is, what exact "extra software packages" and compatibility checks have I missed by installing Ubuntu without connecting to the Internet? How can I install these items outside the Ubuntu installer?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is available on many ISOs, and you've not told us which you used; these ISOs use different installers (thus we don't know if you're asking about a subiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares install) as those can make a difference both to what's included on the ISO (some include more on the install media than others). For kernel modules a simple ubuntu-drivers autoinstall can fix; some OEM kernels may require manual install though - depends on what ISO/installer you used to install 24.04 LTS as you didn't specify specifics. QA is done & internet is NOT required

Ubuntu has an online apt repository where bugfix and security updates and additional programs can be retrieved from. If you do not experience issues, you are not missing out. Once you connect to the internet updates will come.

If using a snap based installer (installer isn't specified; as three are available for 24.04 chosen by ISO downloaded/used) if internet is available the installer can update itself allowing it to be fixed for specific reported issues; this can be of benefit to install issues (esp. if using an older ISO such as original 24.04 ISO released in April 2024; but less so if using a newer ISO & especially daily 24.04 ISO) but this only impacts actual install; not what is installed (as package updates will occur later as per @sleepyhead's comment)

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is offered in a number of products that use different installers, including subiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer and calamares, and what they include/offer differs; so options you have available can be made, or restricted when you select an ISO to download. Some include closed-source kernel modules (aka drivers such as nVIDIA) where others do not.
If you install without internet, and use an ISO that has no closed source kernel modules on it (without internet you cannot download & install anyway either), you can always post-install add them using
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Quality Assurance testing is done to ensure there is no difference between and off-line and online install, that cannot be changed post-install; after all the only differences really are optional packages installed on your system by default (recorded as auto-installed; if you install it later it'll be marked as manually-installed, but that's easily changed anyway)
On some ISOs you'll get extra options offered with an on-line install, those options don't show if off-line, but those are optional packages not found on the ISO, so are downloaded and installed only if selected.
One possibly significant difference between an offline and online install is if using a snap based installer (installer isn't specified; here I mean subiquity or ubuntu-desktop-installer), if internet is available the installer can update itself (it may ask the user to permit this) allowing it to get fixes for specific reported issues; this can be of benefit to install issues (esp. if using an older ISO such as original 24.04 ISO released in April 2024; but less so if using a newer ISO & especially daily 24.04 ISO) but this only impacts the actual install; not what is installed.
The major difference between online & offline are

updates can only be downloaded/installed during install IF internet is available during install
optional packages not found on the ISO or install media cannot be selected to be installed if internet is available and such options exist with your installer/ISO being used, as those packages need to be downloaded to install. Examples will vary on your ISO/installer used; but a quick test using ubuntu-desktop-installer (oracular/24.10) allowed selection of 3rd party software for graphics/hardware but NOT the additional media formats which the installer indicated required internet access to download.

There are other differences selected by ISO/installer used, but all differences can be changed post-install by installing packages using normal apt install or snap install, or sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade commands.

I also use bootable USB to install ubuntu on my new purchased laptop. And before that I googled the steps and it is suggested to not select this step when it comes out. You may do that after you installed it. So that is what I do to skip it. And I could also use this system. Thanks!
